# How does the AIR cache control work, what is the maximum age of cached content?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm currently working on a project that needs to request a url multiple times. Having studied the the HTTP Proxy (Charles) it seems that AIR will cache the first response and then return the same response for each subsequent request.

Does anybody know how to know if the response has been cached other than setting the [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#useCache) to useCache, but this doesn't say if the response was a cached response or not. The [digest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#digest) isn't set on the URLRequest either, although it does mention this is for swz only, so how does it know if the content is the current content or not? Is the responseHeaders used to find out how long to hold the cache i.e.

- Cache-Control: max-age=900

Also does anyone know how to flush/purge the cache or are we at the whim of the GC and in that case how does it know if to leave it in the cache or now?

This makes sense to me, but still I would like to know how to regulate this cache.

**Further more:** I've tested a set up where parallel URLLoaders (10) are made and created which open the same url to see what happens in that instance. It seems that each parallel request is made until a successful response is given, all subsequent calls are then cached. Calls which are sent out before the successful request is then completed. It looks like the items which are already in being processed do not use the cache and return with correct data.

**Additional** The AIR runtime doesn't even send a "If-Modified-Since" header, so the cache isn't even honoring HTTP protocol. So it seems as if Adobe has implemented it's own version of a cache which doesn't even use HTTP/1.1 Header Field Definitions. Perfect.

Thanks for any help.
Simon

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of URLRequest class, it seems that it uses Operating System's HTTP Cache. On a windows 7 OS, it seems that it is using IE's cache.

You can use a HTTP monitor tool like Fiddler, and verify this.

First request is 200, and subsequent requests are 304. After clearing the IE cache. and run the application again, You can see that it results in a HTTP 200 status.